# Best way to call function on selection (including selecting old value)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select field such as the following:

```
<form id="quoteform">
     Go to selection:
     <select id="selector" onchange="gotoselection(this.value)">
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

In my actual example the option values are populated programatically so that there could be any number of options greater than 1.  The listed "onchange" event calls a function that moves the page to the selected value, using scrollIntoView.  It works perfectly except:

I want the user to be able to select the currently selected option and be brought back to the location associated with that option. I believe this could be solved by changing the trigger from "onchange" to something else.  But I'm not sure what would work best for this situation.

Comment: "Associated with that option". Are you saying if you select a, go to somewhere on the page, and if you select b, go somewhere else on the page? Like using anchor tags to go on specific parts on the page?

Comment: Yes. That part is worked out elsewhere (and working). My issue is JUST that i want the function to trigger when the user selects the previously selected option.

So user selects A and is taken to anchor associated with that. Then scrolls away and want to be taken back to A. So they select A again. But nothing will happen because the event is "onchange."

Comment: Oh...I'll see what I can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to do this with pure javascript, but I find it a lot better when you have a library to help you, in this case, I think jQuery UI's [Selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#default) does a good job.

You can see it working on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x59en3r3/), the only hassle is that you may have to setup jquery and jquery ui on your project, but then it gets simple:

```
$(function(){
    $("#selector").selectmenu({
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            alert(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be done with javascript? Why not?

```
<option value="a"><a href="#somewhere">a </a></option>
```

My apologies - that doesn't work (see comments). This works. The main problem that I can see it that it will fire immediately. Added a bool to check if first click. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sp0kchxm/2/)

```
    var firstClick = true;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("click", function(){

                if( firstClick === true ){
                    firstClick = false;
                }
                else{
                    var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
                    alert(selectedValue); 
                    firstClick = true;
                }

            });
        });
```

Comment: What isn't allowed? You want to move to part of the page and you say you're dynamically generating the options?

Comment: 1. I'm not the OP of the question...
2. It's actually not allowed in HTML - you can't put an `<a>` inside a `<option>` It's just one of those things

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Even if it does/could work, it doesn't work for my purposes. I need to trigger the javascript event because the scrolling is more complicated (do to fixed positioned elements). I just need to trigger the js, on any selection (including selecting the most recently selected value), as explained above.